# Как изменять компоненты объектов префаба?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть цикл который создаёт некое число n ,Gameobject(-тов) префаба.

Префаб объекта лидеборда состоит из:

- Image (Родительный объект)
- TMP_Text (Очки)
- TMP_Text (Комбо)
- ImageSprite (Картинка ранга)

Есть скрипт на другом объекте который создаёт эти клоны, и в скрипте лежит `List<Sprite>` который содержит 6 спрайтов для того что бы использовать их в префабе при создании.

---

Хочу сделать так: Создаётся клон префаба, в зависимости от условий, `ImageSprite` брал бы `Sprite` из листа на другом объекте и засовывал в себя, так же и с `TMP_Text`, все значения лежат в скрипте другого объекта в `List<string>`.

---

Пожалуйста помогите если есть знатоки или предложите другое решение, желательно без костылей.

Comment: Ты не пробовал банально книжки для начинающих почитать по Юнити? Всё это есть в книгах.

Comment: Помочь в чём? Код написать что-ли за тебя?  С таким ты ресурсом ошибся, это к фрилансерам!

Answer (score -3):

Все что нужно было сделать это, сначала получить ссылку на объект ImageSprite и TMP_Text в вашем префабе. После этого вы можете установить им нужные значения из списка спрайтов и текста.

вот пример кода:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PrefabScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Sprite> spriteList; // Список спрайтов
    public List<string> textList;   // Список текстов

    private Image imageComponent;
    private TMP_Text textComponent1;
    private TMP_Text textComponent2;
    private Image imageSpriteComponent;

    private void Start()
    {
        
        imageComponent = GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
        textComponent1 = GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>();
        textComponent2 = GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>();
        imageSpriteComponent = GetComponentInChildren<ImageSprite>();


        SetSpriteAndText();
    }

    private void SetSpriteAndText()
    {

        if (spriteList.Count > 0)
        {

            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, spriteList.Count);

            imageSpriteComponent.sprite = spriteList[randomIndex];
        }

        if (textList.Count > 0)
        {

            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, textList.Count);

            textComponent1.text = textList[randomIndex];
            textComponent2.text = textList[randomIndex]; 
        }
    }
}
```